# Continuity equation for topologically equivalent VFs

Tags: probability, general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems

Let $f$ be a $\mathcal{C}^1$ vector field (VF) on a compact subset $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. $M$ inherits the Euclidean metric. We define a dynamical system by
$$\dot{x}(t)=f(x(t))$$
The dynamical systems is topologically equivalent to another systems (with VF $g$) if we can map orbits to orbits, preserving the time direction. More precisely on the level of VF there has to exist a diffeomorphism $h: M \rightarrow M$ such that
$$f=(Dh)^{-1}(x)g(h(x))$$
with the Jacobian $Dh$ of $h$.

Given some distribution of initial conditions $\rho_{0}$, the time evolution under the flow of $f$ is defined by

$$\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\rho_{t}+\operatorname{div}(f \rho)=0 & x \in M, t>0 \\ \rho(x,0)=\rho_0 & x \in M\end{array}\right.$$

Let $\mu(t,x)$ now be the evolution of $\rho_0$, (i.e. $\mu(x,0)=\rho_0$) but under $g$ instead of $f$.

---

**My question is the following:** Can we establish a relation of $\mu$ in terms of $\rho$. I.e. can we write $\mu$ in terms of some (closed) expression involving $\rho$ and $h$.

---

I am also happy to anybody pointing me to the literature, if a related problem was already studied.

Comment: Well I think first some clarification is needed. Since you want to talk about $f$ and $g$ being related by pushforward you need to have that the map $h$ is at least a $\mathcal{C}^1$ diffeomorphism. 

Furthermore since you're talking about divergence on $M$ one needs to clarify what metric you're using, I assume you're talking about the induced metric $\eta=\iota^*\left((dx^1)^2+\cdots+(dx^n)^2\right)$ by the inclusion map $\iota:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$. Having a metric will give us a well defined divergence on the manifold $M$ which locally depends on the determinant of the metric.

Comment: Yes, I edited the question.